# How to get the downoladURL from files uploaded with AngularFireStorage referenced in a collection

Tags: angular5, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, angularfire2

### I'm using Angular v"5.2.0" and angularfire2 v"5.0.0-rc.6"

I'm uploading images to a storage location using angularfire2, and I'm referencing them to a collection called photos:
The collection has this structure:

- teamName:"teamName"
- path:"storageLocation/fileName.jpg"
- size:"4544"

  ```
  <div *ngFor="let team  of teams |async">
   <h3>{{ team.teamName }}</h3>
   <img class="card-img-top" [src]="team.path" width=50px>
   <button class="button is-danger" (click)="close()">Close</button>
  </div>
  ```

The example provided in the documentation says i have to point to the specific locationPath to call the functions to retrieve to downloadURl

```
constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) {
 const ref = this.storage.ref('users/davideast.jpg');
 this.profileUrl = ref.getDownloadUrl();
}
```

Is there any way to retrieve the downloadURL from a list of documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I did it was to create a pipe and pass through the img with *ngIf:

```
    <div *ngFor="let photo of photos | async">
    <img class="galleryImage" *ngIf="photo.path | downloadUrl | async as photoUrl" [src]="photoUrl">
    </div>
```

The pipe 'downloadUrl' uses the .getDownloadURL() function from angularfire2:

```
    @Pipe({name: 'downloadUrl'})

    export class DownloadUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {

        constructor(public storage: AngularFireStorage){}

        transform(featuredPhoto: any): any {
            let photo = this.storage.ref(featuredPhoto).getDownloadURL().do(console.log);
            return photo;
        }
    }
```